# How can I calculate the Union of rectangles using a divide-and-conquer algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

How to calculate the Union of rectangles? Each rectangle is given as top_left and bottom_right point.
The Union algorithm should be act follows:
Given a set of rectangles, output another set of rectangles which is not overlapped but the covered area is equal to the original set.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY4Uf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCOAQ.png)

I want to use a divide and conquer algorithm, I divide the given set into 2 set recursively until only one rectangle in the set(just like what merge sort would do).For a set which only contains one
rectangle

```py
def merge_rectangles(rects:list):
    assert len(rects) >0, "rects should not be empty"
    if len(rects)==1:
        return rects[0]
    else:
        left_half=merge_rectangles(rects[:len(rects)//2])
        right_half=merge_rectangles(rects[len(rects)//2:])
        # how to merge the left half and right half
```

Comment: Calculate the intersection and if there is one, split your original rectangles in smaller ones without the intersection.

Comment: Why do you think divide-and-conquer is a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to follow a divide-and-conquer pattern. It's not applicable to your problem, because the combination stage may have complexity equal to that of the subproblems.

The easiest efficient approach here is probably a sweep-line algorithm. Make a list of left and right rectangle extents, then sort it. Then iterate through the left-right sorted set, adding and removing "active" rectangles. Between each two consecutive events in the list -- that is, in an X range where the set of rectangles is constant -- compute the area of that range (given the active rectangles, and given overlaps) and add it to a running sum. To make this efficient, you will need to use an interval tree to track the active rectangles.